# while-loop that subtracts 6.3 from the number 934 until the number * is between (not equal to) 47 and 57

Tags: php

```
$number = 934;
$minus = 6.3;

while($number > 47 || $number < 57) {
 $number = $number - $minus;
}


echo $number;
```

I want to create an while-loop that subtracts 6.3 from the number 934 until the number  * is between (not equal to) 47 and 57. Can someone help me out with this? Now im getting only infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an infinite loop because the `while` condition never gets satisfied at the start.

What might work better is checking the number in the loop and `break`'ing if it's within the range:

```
$number = 934;
$minus = 6.3;

while(true) {
   $number = $number - $minus;
   if ($number < 57 && $number > 47) {
      break;
   }
}

echo $number; //52.000000000002
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$number = 934;
$minus = 6.3;
while($number > 47) {
 $number = $number - $minus;
if($number > 47 && $number < 57){
echo $number."</br>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This won't stop after finding the first number. It will print out all the numbers in the 47 - 57 range that meet the criteria.